# Android SDK Azure Mobile Apps - SQL Database Table query list error: "Cannot resolve method 'get()'"

Tags: android, database, azure, sdk

I am trying to query a table in Azure Mobile Apps based on the example docs.  I have a table of serial numbers and MAC addresses and I am writing a method to query a serial number and return the MAC address.

I get the error on the last .get();

```
public String serialToMac(String serial) {
    List<Router> result = routerTable
            .where()
            .field("serial").eq(serial)
            .select("mac")
            .execute()
            .get();
    return result.get(0).toString();
```

I can't seem to identify what is causing this.  Help is much appreciated!

Microsoft Azure Docs for Mobile App Service Client Library (with Database routines):
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library)

Comment: The `get()` or the `get(0)`?

Comment: second to last line:
get();

Comment: What is `routerTable`?

Comment: routerTable:
MobileServiceTable<Router> routerTable = mClient.getTable(Router.class);

Below is the Router class inside RouterTable.java - Android Studio complains that it should be Router.java but if I'm reading the docs correctly they say to define a public class inside a .java file of a different name (MyDataTable.java contains public class ToDoItem)

public class Router {
    private String id;
    private String mac;
    private String serial;
    private String coachid;
    private String lan_ip;

Comment: Have you tried building? the `get()` method should exist.

Comment: Thanks that helped!  That showed me a better error - error: cannot access ListenableFuture class file for com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture not found - which led me to adding Guava to my app gradle script, and now the error is gone.  Now to troubleshoot other errors!  Thanks!